# How to write a simple jquery to store the last selected values of two dropdowns and one text box in partial view

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdownlist in mvc which as shown below. As of now the issue i am facing is when validation fails the view(partial) is not maintaining 
previously selected value.So i am thinking to write some jquery to store the last selected value and i will set a flag there in controller like 
Viewbag.error = true; then display the controls with last selected values rather than default.
here is the exisitng code which contains two dropdownbox and one text box  and all are in Ajax.beignform , one more thing is second dropdown is
getting value based on first dropdown value as result of Jason

so this the code

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("_firstGridAll", "mnis", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "PsitegridContent" }))
{

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

            <div style="float: left">
                @Html.Label("lbRegion", "Region*")
                @*@Html.ValidationMessage("REGION_CODE", "*")*@

                @Html.DropDownList("REGION_CODE", (SelectList)ViewBag.Categories, "Select region code")
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.REGION_CODE)

            </div>

            <div class="tested">
                @Html.Label("lblSubregion", "Sub Region*")
                @*@Html.ValidationMessage("GEO_ZONE_CODE", "*")*@
                @*            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.GEO_ZONE_CODE)*@
                <select id="GEO_ZONE_CODE" name="GEO_ZONE_CODE"></select>

            </div>

            <div class="tested">
                @Html.Label("lblSiteid", "Site Id*")
                @*@Html.ValidationMessage("PSITE_ID", "*")*@

                @*<input type="text" id="PSITE_ID" name="PSITE_ID" />*@
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PSITE_ID)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PSITE_ID)

            </div>

            <div class="Testedagain">

                <input type="submit" value="Search" />

            </div>
}
```

Comment: May be this is an ugly way, but as of now this coming into my mind and it will be quick

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the view would lose the values of the properties but here's some code to store the values which you can then post to your controller?

Updated answer to use localstorage. Now the data will be persisted even after a page refresh. But make sure you clear out the values on a successful post to ensure the user does not submit the wrong values the next time he/she uses the form.

HTML:

```
<label for="REGION_CODE">REGION_CODE: </label>
<select id="REGION_CODE">
    <option id="0" value="0">---</option>
    <option id="1" value="1">1</option>
    <option id="2" value="2">2</option>
</select>
<br />
<label for="GEO_ZONE_CODE">GEO_ZONE_CODE: </label>
<select id="GEO_ZONE_CODE">
    <option id="0" value="0">---</option>
    <option id="1" value="1">1</option>
    <option id="2" value="2">2</option>    
</select>
<br />
<label for="PSITE_ID">PSITE_ID: </label>
<input type="text" id ="PSITE_ID" />
<br />
<button type="button" id="refresh">Refresh Window</button>
```

JS:

```
(function(){
    $("#refresh").click(function() {
        location.reload();
        console.log("regionCodeValue after refresh is: " + localStorage.regionCodeValue);
        console.log("geoCodeValue after refresh is: " + localStorage.geoCodeValue);
        console.log("pSiteId after refresh is: " + localStorage.pSiteId);
    });

    $("#REGION_CODE").change(function() {
        localStorage.regionCodeValue = this.value;
        console.log("regionCodeValue is: " + localStorage.regionCodeValue);
    });

    $("#GEO_ZONE_CODE").change(function() {
        localStorage.geoCodeValue = this.value;
        console.log("geoCodeValue is: " + localStorage.geoCodeValue);
    });

    $("#PSITE_ID").change(function() {
        localStorage.pSiteId = this.value;
        console.log("pSiteId is: " + localStorage.pSiteId);
    });

    //Call jquery to post the values to your controller?
    //On Success, call the following:
    //localStorage.pSiteId = '';
    //localStorage.geoCodeValue = '';
    //localStorage.regionCodeValue = '';
})();
```

[JSFiddle source](https://jsfiddle.net/e83ncanj/1/). Adapt the code to your correct input ID's.

Comment: what i am saying is value iam losing when post back happens and after that when the validation fails, again the same page will be loaded giving a chance to renter customer values.As of now two dropdownlist and text boxt box resetting values

Comment: one more thing is second dropdown is loaded based on first dropdown and if cutomer enter some wrong values in textbox validation fails and will come to same page after postback in order to renter values

Comment: So you're looking for a way to persist the values even after there is a page refresh/post back? If so, I could adapt the answer to use localstorage? That is messy but could work.

Comment: Yea that is the one i am expecting